Converting dataframe to json with nested arrays
I am new to python and to pandas and having trouble converting my dataframe into a json format with nested arrays
My dataframe is as follows:
Colours
I am trying to create json output in the following format which has nested arrays of details per arrays of type and colour:
{
  "types": [
    {
      "A": [
        {
          "colour": "RED",
          "code": "R",
          "details": [
            {
              "id": "11a",
              "value": "166.23"
            },
            {
              "id": "12b",
              "value": "999.99"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "colour": "BLUE",
          "code": "B",
          "details": [
            {
              "id": "44a",
              "value": "12.33"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "B": [
        {
          "colour": "RED",
          "code": "R",
          "details": [
            {
              "id": "66y",
              "value": "12345.00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I have tried grouping by type and colour but I don't get an array per type
I'm also not sure how to get the details array containing the id and value column headings from my dataframe.
json output gives:
[{"type":"A","colour":"BLUE","code":"B","details":[["44a",12.33]]},{"type":"A","colour":"RED","code":"R","details":[["11a",166.23],["12b",999.99]]},{"type":"B","colour":"RED","code":"R","details":[["66y",12345.0]]}]

Dictionary gives:
{('A', 'BLUE'): {'code': 'B', 'details': [['44a', 12.33]]}, ('A', 'RED'): {'code': 'R', 'details': [['11a', 166.23], ['12b', 999.99]]}, ('B', 'RED'): {'code': 'R', 'details': [['66y', 12345.0]]}}

I'm not sure whether this is the right direction to take to get to the json I'm aiming for.
Code so far giving above json and dictionary:
df = pd.read_excel("/Colours.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Colour',index_col =[0])
df['details'] = df.apply(lambda x: list([x['id'],x['value']]),axis=1)
df_grouped = df.groupby(["type", "colour","code"]).details.agg(list).reset_index()
output = df_grouped.to_json(orient='records')
df_grouped = df_grouped.set_index(['type', 'colour'])
df_dict= df_grouped.to_dict(orient='index')`


This code delivers an output similar to the one you requested.
Code
import pandas as pd

list_colors = []
list_colors.append(["A","RED","R","11a",166.23])
list_colors.append(["A","RED","R","12a",999.99])
list_colors.append(["A","BLUE","B","44a",12.33])
list_colors.append(["B","RED","R","66y",12345.00])

df = pd.DataFrame(list_colors,columns=["type","colour","code","id","value"])

nested_df = (df.groupby(['type','colour','code'])
       .apply(lambda x: x[['id','value']].to_dict('records'), include_groups=False)
       .reset_index()
       .rename(columns={0:'details'})
       .groupby(['type'])
       .apply(lambda x: x[['colour','code','details']].to_dict('records'), include_groups=False)
)

parent_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'types': nested_df
})

parent_df = parent_df.to_json()

parent_df

Output
'{"types":{"A":[{"colour":"BLUE","code":"B","details":[{"id":"44a","value":12.33}]},{"colour":"RED","code":"R","details":[{"id":"11a","value":166.23},{"id":"12a","value":999.99}]}],"B":[{"colour":"RED","code":"R","details":[{"id":"66y","value":12345.0}]}]}}'

this post was usefull:
Convert Pandas Dataframe to nested JSON

You'll probably need to change some more code between nested_df and parent_df so that the "types" object has a list of elements

Thanks very much @camilo_chart - this is very helpful!

It's good to know that the post is helpful. Seeing that you are a new user I would like to suggest that you can vote above this post if you liked it. Other users will be able to continue posting solutions until it is marked as solved.
